# Linux command to use gmail API

Tags: linux, gmail-api

I am trying to use #gmail-api to retrieve the info in my profile:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userID/profile
But when I run it I get:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thx!

Comment: have you tried using basic authorization andby providing a username and password , you need to do that first

Answer (score 1):

Login Required means just that you must be logged in to make that call. In order to access private data you must first have permission to access said data.   In the case of the Gmail api you need to use Oauth2.

While you can use a http get to call [Users: getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userID/profile
```

you must attach the access token from the Oauth authentication flow to the end of it.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userID/profile?access_token=MyToken
```

Getting the access token in the first place will require http posts and http gets.   Documentation can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth)